# Flink metric `flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Load{}` is not accurate in Grafana Dashboard

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple Flink job, and the Kafka consumption rate is like **5,000/s**.

- Parallelism: **1**
- Job Manager: 1 GB
- Task Manager: 2 GB
- Flink version: **1.10.2**

But from what I observed, the CPU usage is too low. So I think if it's possible that, in this version, the Flink metrics is not accurate. Or maybe it's because I configured wrong PromQL?

Query for the Grafana chart:

```
flink_jobmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Load{exported_job='${jobmanager_prome_job}'}
```

[image]

Update task manager chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your title you actually want to check the load on the taskmanager (which is more interesting in most cases anyways). Could you adjust your Grafana chart to use the taskmanager instead of the jobmanager and report back? Note that CPU is at 1 only if all cores are fully saturated on that machine. So if you have 10 cores in your machine, you'd get at most 0.1 if you run with parallelism 1.

Comment: Hi, Arvid. I attached the taskmanager report. You can see that the rate is never reach 0.0125. Is it depends on how many vCores my cluster/node have?  Now we have 400 vCores  on the Yarn cluster.

Comment: By the way, I think you're right. It makes sense when the rate X the number of cores. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I could help.